# Java JVM Error: Could not find or load main class After Much Debugging

Tags: java

I tried all I can to solve this, did all the research. Still cannot solve it. Am I missing something?

This is my current directory

```
$ pwd
/Applications/apache-tomcat-9.0.8/webapps/masterwarehousing_topdown/generatedWrappers/16451886466

$ ls -la
-rw-r-----   1 user  staff  7841 Jul 12 16:50 XMLEliteExtraction16451886466.java
```

In this file, the class is not in any package:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Vector;
import edu.gatech.disl.inforetrieval.*;
import edu.gatech.disl.inforetrieval.seqalignment.*;
import edu.gatech.disl.inforetrieval.codegeneration.WrapperTemplate;
import edu.gatech.disl.qr.util.Base64;

public class XMLEliteExtraction16451886466 extends WrapperTemplate {

public XMLEliteExtraction16451886466() {
    ....
    public static void main(java.lang.String[] args) { ....
```

I compiled this successfully with:

```
Users-MacBook-Air:16451886466 user$ javac XMLEliteExtraction16451886466.java -cp /Applications/apache-tomcat-9.0.8/lib/servlet-api.jar:/Applications/apache-tomcat-9.0.8/webapps/masterwarehousing_topdown/WEB-INF/classes:/Applications/apache-tomcat-9.0.8/webapps/masterwarehousing_topdown/WEB-INF/lib/adc.jar:/Applications/apache-tomcat-9.0.8/webapps/masterwarehousing_topdown/WEB-INF/lib/axis-ant.jar:/Applications/apache-tomcat-9.0.8/webapps/masterwarehousing_topdown/WEB-INF/lib/axis.jar:/Applications/apache-tomcat-9.0.8/webapps/masterwarehousing_topdown/WEB-INF/lib/cleanomini.jar:/Applications/apache-tomcat-9.0.8/webapps/masterwarehousing_topdown/WEB-INF/lib/commons-discovery.jar:/Applications/apache-tomcat-9.0.8/webapps/masterwarehousing_topdown/WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging.jar:/Applications/apache-tomcat-9.0.8/webapps/masterwarehousing_topdown/WEB-INF/lib/gnu.jar:/Applications/apache-tomcat-9.0.8/webapps/masterwarehousing_topdown/WEB-INF/lib/jaxrpc.jar:/Applications/apache-tomcat-9.0.8/webapps/masterwarehousing_topdown/WEB-INF/lib/jgl.jar:/Applications/apache-tomcat-9.0.8/webapps/masterwarehousing_topdown/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-1.2.8.jar:/Applications/apache-tomcat-9.0.8/webapps/masterwarehousing_topdown/WEB-INF/lib/oracle12.jar:/Applications/apache-tomcat-9.0.8/webapps/masterwarehousing_topdown/WEB-INF/lib/pagesentinel.jar:/Applications/apache-tomcat-9.0.8/webapps/masterwarehousing_topdown/WEB-INF/lib/rt.jar:/Applications/apache-tomcat-9.0.8/webapps/masterwarehousing_topdown/WEB-INF/lib/saaj.jar:/Applications/apache-tomcat-9.0.8/webapps/masterwarehousing_topdown/WEB-INF/lib/tidyr7.jar:/Applications/apache-tomcat-9.0.8/webapps/masterwarehousing_topdown/WEB-INF/lib/util.jar:/Applications/apache-tomcat-9.0.8/webapps/masterwarehousing_topdown/WEB-INF/lib/wsdl4j.jar:/Applications/apache-tomcat-9.0.8/webapps/masterwarehousing_topdown/WEB-INF/lib/xalan.jar:/Applications/apache-tomcat-9.0.8/webapps/masterwarehousing_topdown/WEB-INF/lib/xerces_1.4.3.jar:/Applications/apache-tomcat-9.0.8/webapps/masterwarehousing_topdown/WEB-INF/lib/xml-apis.jar -Xlint:deprecation -Xlint:unchecked
```

in my current directory.

But when I load it with the jvm, I get this:

```
$ java -cp /Applications/apache-tomcat-9.0.8/webapps/masterwarehousing_topdown/generatedWrappers/16451886466 XMLEliteExtraction16451886466
Error: Could not find or load main class XMLEliteExtraction16451886466
```

Same here:

```
$ java XMLEliteExtraction16451886466
Error: Could not find or load main class XMLEliteExtraction16451886466
```

Comment: Is that the complete stacktrace?  If not, please include the complete stacktrace, including any nested exceptions.

Comment: hello @stephenC it is the complete stacktrace

Comment: The problem is that your compile time and runtime classpaths are substantially different.  The JARs you need at compile time are also needed at runtime.  (See the linked Q&A)

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to specify the full qualified class name (ok, does not apply with no package) and check that the class has a main method with signature, return type and modifiers given by

public static void main(String[])

see [What does "Could not find or load main class" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean)

Comment: yup there is public static void main(java.lang.String[] args) {

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
java -cp ./:/Applications/apache-tomcat-9.0.8/webapps/masterwarehousing_topdown/generatedWrappers/16451886466 XMLEliteExtraction16451886466
```

Comment: I'd give my upvote, if your answer had an explanation

Comment: same error: java -cp ./:/Applications/apache-tomcat-9.0.8/webapps/masterwarehousing_topdown/generatedWrappers/16451886466 XMLEliteExtraction16451886466
Error: Could not find or load main class XMLEliteExtraction16451886466

Comment: @Paul I am sorry that I didn't give details. It was not clear where the class file was present and it was mentioned that pwd was where the class file was, I asked the pwd to be added to the classpath.

Comment: @forgodsakehold could you please try with same classpath as the compilation classpath, the error could be during loading the mail class as well.